# Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) with AngularJS and ElasticSearch

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I'm working on an Angular 1.6.3 app which uses the elasticsearch.js library to query an ElasticSearch 5.4 instance running on a remote server. Recently, our app started having problems where it receives several `Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` errors when it initially reaches out to ElasticSearch for data. Currently this problem only happens in Chrome:

[image: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)]

Screenshot of request in Developer Tools:[image: HTTP request in network tab]

This error seems to happen randomly, and it doesn't occur when a user accesses the app in Chrome's Incognito Mode or another browser like Firefox.

After doing some research, I found out that this `OPTIONS` request is a preflight request the browser sends out to ask the server if it's okay to send the actual `POST` containing what I want to query ElasticSearch for. The reason a preflight is occurring is because I am trying to do a POST with `application/json` as the `Content-Type` header, which isn't one of the "standard" values for the `Content-Type` header.

My question is - how do I resolve this? I've changed the CORS settings in `elasticsearch.yml` to no avail:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
```

I've also tried changing the elasticsearch.js `Content-Type` headers for each ElasticSearch request but each request continues to send `application/json`, like the settings don't listen to what I enter:

```
var client = elasticsearch.Client({
  hosts: [{
    host: 'es-proxy.company.net',
    port: 80,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }]
});
```

A screenshot of the `OPTION` request that fails from Chrome DevTool net-internals event page:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of problem can be seen in the Chrome DevTool net-internals event page near the bottom of the `OPTION` request, where it says `CHROME_EXTENSION_REDIRECTED_REQUEST`. A Chrome extension was randomly redirecting my requests to ElasticSearch, effectively cancelling them. Since it is a Chrome extension that was installed by my company (through an enterprise policy) and thus unremovable, I was able to get the ElasticSearch host added to the extension's whitelist.